# App crashes when alertDialog is shown for the second time

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

so i want to use a custom dialog which contains an edittext; and the edittext has a textwatcher to convert the text inside of it.
when i click the button for the first time and the dialog shows up, everything is fine but the second time the whole app crashes with this error : "The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first ".
i searched and tried almost everything but none of them worked.
here is the code:

```
var dialogView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog, null, false)
var edittext = dialogView.findViewById<EditText>(R.id.alert_edittext)


findViewById<Button>(R.id.total_price_manual_input_button).setOnClickListener {
    //edittext=layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog, null, false).findViewById(R.id.alert_edittext)
    val builder = AlertDialog.Builder(this@MainActivity)
    builder.setView(dialogView)
        .create()
        .show()
}

}
```

i read on some topics that i have to create a new instance of the dialogview every time the dialog is being shown but when i tried to pass the "layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog, null, false)" directly to the setView(), the textwatcher did not get called.

also i tried to cast the dialogView parent as ViewGroup in order to cal removeView() on it but i got nullPointerException.

Comment: Move top 2 lines inside the On click . you are trying to use same view everytime thats why you getting this crash . Create View each time when you create dialog .

Comment: when i do that the addTextChangedListener does not get called. so the changes i want to make on the text wont be applied.

Comment: It will get called you need to move all that code inside the block where you create the Dialog .. Do not use any global variable with dialog view ..

Comment: Thank you a lot! this worked perfectly.moving the textchangedlistener to the block saved me.